# Python match string if it does not start with X

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to search for a file called "AcroTray.exe" on my disk. The program should print a warning **if the file is located in a directory other than "Distillr"**.
I used the following Syntax to perform the negative match

```
(?!Distillr)
```

The problem is that although I use the "!" it always produces a MATCH. I tried to figure out the problem using IPython but failed. 
This is what I tried:

```
import re

filePath = "C:\Distillr\AcroTray.exe"

if re.search(r'(?!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe', filePath):
    print "MATCH"
```

It prints a MATCH.
What is wrong with my regex?

I would like to get a match on:

```
C:\SomeDir\AcroTray.exe
```

But not on:

```
C:\Distillr\AcroTray.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative **lookbehind** (`(?<!...)`), not negative lookahead:

```
if re.search(r'(?<!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe', filePath):
```

---

This matches:

```
In [45]: re.search(r'(?<!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe', r'C:\SomeDir\AcroTray.exe')
Out[45]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xb57f448>
```

This does not match:

```
In [46]: re.search(r'(?<!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe', r'C:\Distillr\AcroTray.exe')
# None
```

Comment: Ha. Damn.
I had to extend the regex because the file could be in two directories.

`if re.search(r'(?<!Distillr|!Acrobat)\\AcroTray\.exe', filePath):`

But that requires a fixed with I cant give.

Comment: Ah - got it. If I use two expressions, the second on has to be shorter than the first one. `(?<!Acrobat|!Distillr)` fails with an "fixed-width" error.  `(?<!Distillr|!Acrobat)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use negative look-behind: `(?<!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You want a look *behind*, not a lookahead. Like this:

```
(?<!Distillr)\\AcroTray\.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?mx)^((?!Distillr).)*$`

Looking at the examples you provided, I uses them as examples [here](http://rubular.com/r/zMfbJnCQuT)